# handlebar precompile version error in Ember rc5

Tags: ember.js, bundler, handlebars.js, ember-rails

I'm upgrading to Ember rc5 from rc3, but I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0-rc.4) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (== 1.0.0-rc.3)`

Here are the relevant lines in my gemfile, taken [straight from the ember-rails README](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) (except pulling the gem from git... it gives the same error whether I include that or not)

```
gem 'ember-rails', git: 'https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0.rc5'
gem 'handlebars-source', '1.0.0.rc4'
```

I'm using rails 3.2

I know this problem has come up before, but none of the solutions I've found have made a difference.  Things that haven't worked:

- deleting precompiled assets
- rake tmp:clear
- making sure my javascrcipt load order is jquery, then handlebars, then ember
- restarting the server
- threatening the compiler
- giving up hope and watching Buffy reruns
- trying all of those in conjunction, in every imaginable order

Simple and definitive answers are best, of course, but I'd also be glad for hints on what I can study to figure this out on my own.  I don't know where to start.

Comment: I've opened an issue about it: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, ensure your Gemfile is using the edge version:

```
gem 'ember-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0.rc5'
gem 'handlebars-source', '1.0.0.rc4'
```

A new version of the gem should be released to resolve the issue soon. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Although that was what I had before, and it didn't work then, it appears to be working now.  Thanks for opening the issue and working on this.