# Upgrade ember-precompile without rails or grunt

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am writing an ember app, and not using rails nor grunt for anything. I previously had a short python program that took text files and did some `markdown` stuff with them, and then compiled them all to a `templates.js` file using `ember-precompile`:

```
ember-precompile templates/*.hbs -f templates/templates.js
```

This worked great until I upgraded ember, and now I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime.
Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (== 1.0.0-rc.3).
```

I need to upgrade my ember-precompile program, but solutions like [changing a grunt config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131611/not-possible-to-use-the-latest-ember-with-pre-compiled-templates) or [changing gemfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894417/handlebar-precompile-version-error-in-ember-rc5) are no good for me, since I'm not using either of those tools.

Also, attempts to [upgrade](http://www.continuousthinking.com/2013/05/19/ember-precompile-for-ember-1-0-0-rc-3.html) or [reinstall](https://npmjs.org/package/ember-precompile) haven't made any changes at all.

Ember version `Version: v1.0.0
Last commit: e2ea0cf (2013-08-31 23:47:39 -0700)`

Handlebars version `Handlebars.VERSION = "1.0.0";`

Feel free to fill in any gaps in my understanding. For short term development purposes I'm just going to put my templates in `index.html` but I want to do markdown stuff to my templates first, so that won't do forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to learn the magic of github and npm and download a non "release" version of the program and install it. Pretty stupid of me really.

If anyone in the future has this problem, just check out [npm install](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) and get one of the fixed versions from github in a zip file or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to recompile your handlebar files using the latest ember-precompile version that matches the run time version. Basically, ember-precompile that you are using is older version but you are currently running the newer version of ember. That is what the compliant is about.

Comment: I'm already aware of that, but I'm trying to upgrade my `ember-precompile` but I haven't been able to. I edited my post to make that clear.